# try OpenGL instead of ANGLE - what?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I tested webgl app (based on Three.JS), got this message:

"WebGLRenderer: too many bones - 80, this GPU supports just 58 (try OpenGL instead of ANGLE)"
i.imgur.com/0RijQ6n.png

Help from Three.JS communiti:

1. For google chrome "solution":
   "run chrome with the --use-gl=desktop command-line argument."
   http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/webgl/
2. For firefox "solution":
   "Just switch the about:config preference webgl.prefer-native-gl to true."
   http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2090351&start=15
3. In IE app not work at all. (because webgl not supported until windows 8.1 will come)

All work fine after "switching".

But can i use in my app something like "force OpenGL" - to ensure that users will not have to do anything extra for that application would be earned?

P.S. ANGLE - "Almost Native Graphics Layer Engine" code.google.com/p/angleproject

Comment: The same problem appears on that Three.js example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_morph.html

Comment: On Win 8.1 Preview problem appears on GTX 560 TI o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nope.** The WebGL rendering API is for the whole browser, not something you can set from a webpage.

Best you can do is give the user clear, easy to understand instructions to change the setting.